# The longest Olympic winning streak for a nation

Tags: trivia, olympics, records

Asking this [question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/10742/the-longest-olympic-winning-streak/10743#10743) I was thinking about the longest gold medal streak for a nation in a speciality.

So it mean both summer and winter Olympic games and also for team or individual speciality.

For individual is allowed also if an athlete from a Country wins the gold medal following another athlete coming from the same Country

Comment: According to [this website](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/most-consecutive-olympic-gold-medals-won-), 6 consecutive gold medal of [Aladar Gerevich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alad%C3%A1r_Gerevich) are record for an individual athlete.

Comment: [USA men's basketball team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_men%27s_national_basketball_team#Competitive_record) has 7 consecutive gold medals.

Comment: The Soviet women's gymnastics team won the first of its eight consecutive gold medals in [1952 Helsinki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1952_Summer_Olympics).
See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_gymnastics_(women)#All-Around.2C_Team

Comment: @Martin: That should be 9 for the basketball team, but for some [very sketchy referee decisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1972_Olympic_Men%27s_Basketball_Final).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a [community wiki answer](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info). Feel free to update post, if needed, or add more streaks, especially if they are longer than the ones already listed. (Ideally with some reference.)

**Streaks of at least 10 gold medals**

- A USA athlete won the gold medal in the [men's pole vault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_vault_at_the_Olympics) in the first **16 Summer Olympic Games**.
  This streak is also listed in the Wikipedia article on [winning streaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_streak#Athletics).
- Soviet/Russian competitors won **12 consecutive gold medals** in [figure skating - pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_figure_skating#Pairs) at Winter Olympics from 1964 to 2006. This record is listed in Wikipedia article on [winning streaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_streak_(sports)#Figure_skating).
- A USA athlete won the gold medal in the [3m springboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_diving#3_metre_springboard) in **11 consecutive Summer Olympic Games** from 1920 to 1950. This streak is also listed in the Wikipedia article on [winning streaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_streak_(sports)#Aquatic_Sports).
- USA team won **10 consecutive Olympic golds** in [4x100m medley relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_swimming_(men)#4_.C3.97_100_metres_medley_relay) from 1984 to 2020. USA won this discipline on all Olympic Games where this discipline featured, with the exception of the boycott of [1980 Moscow Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1980_Summer_Olympics_boycott). If we exclude the boycotted games, this would be **14 consecutive gold medals** (i.e., all Olympic Games where this discipline featured). This streak is also listed in the Wikipedia article on [winning streaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_streak_(sports)#4.C3.97100m_Medley_Relay).
- A Kenyan athlete won the [3000 m Steeplechase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steeplechase_at_the_Olympics) at **9 consecutive Olympic Games** from 1984 to 2016. This streak is also listed in the Wikipedia article on [winning streaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_streak_(sports)#3000m_Steeplechase). The streak ended in 2020, when Soufiane El Bakkali from Morocco won this discipline. However, if we do not count the 1976 and 1980 Olympic Games - where Kenya did not participate - we get to total of **11 gold medals**. See [Fillet's answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/10749/the-longest-olympic-winning-for-a-nation/10751#10751) for more details.

**Ongoing streaks of at least 6 gold medals**

- A Chinese competitor won the women's singles competition in [table tennis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_tennis_at_the_Summer_Olympics#Women.27s_singles) at **9 consecutive Olympic Games** from 1988 to 2020. This means that a Chinese competitor has won this discipline each time it has featured in the Olympics so far. This streak is also listed in the Wikipedia article on [winning streaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_streak_(sports)#Table_Tennis).
- A Chinese competitor won the [women's 3m springboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_diving#3_metre_springboard_2) at **9 consecutive Olympic Games** from 1988 to 2020.
- South Korean team won [women's archery team competition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_archery#Women.27s_events) at **9 consecutive Olympic Games** from 1988 to 2020. That is, they won gold at all Olympics where this discipline was part of the program. This streak is also listed in the Wikipedia article on [winning streaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_streak_(sports)#Archery).
- USA team won [women's 4x400m relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%C3%97400_metres_relay_at_the_Olympics#Women) at  **7 consecutive Olympics** from 1996 to 2020. This streak is also listed in the Wikipedia article on [winning streaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_streak_(sports)#4x400m_Relay_2).
- USA team won [women's basketball tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball_at_the_Summer_Olympics#Women.27s_tournaments) **7 consecutive Olympics** from 1996 to 2020. This streak is also listed in the Wikipedia article on [winning streaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_streak_(sports)#Basketball).
- A German competitor won gold medal in [women's singles luge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_luge#Women%27s_singles) at **6 consecutive Winter Olympics** from 1998 to 2018.
- China won [synchronized 10 metre platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_diving#Synchronized_10_metre_platform_2) at **6 consecutive Olympic Games** from 2000 to 2020 - each time when this event was featured.
- A competitor from Great Britain won [one-person heavyweight dinghy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_sailing_by_discipline#One-person_heavyweight_dinghy) at **6 consecutive Olympic Games** from 2000 to 2020.
- Russia won both duet and team in [synchronized swimming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_synchronized_swimming) at **6 consecutive Olympic Games** from 2000 to 2020.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe there is more somewhere, but any nation will have done very well to beat the [Kenyan streak](http://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/sports/ATH/mens-3000-metres-steeplechase.html) in the [3000m Men's Steeplechase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steeplechase_at_the_Olympics).

The last non-Kenyan to win the race was the Pole Bronisław Malinowski in 1980. Since then 8 different Kenyans have won 9 gold medals in a row.

- [2016 Conseslus Kipruto](http://www.sbnation.com/2016/8/17/12515362/olympics-2016-results-3000m-steeplechase-mens-gold-medal-conseslus-kipruto-evan-jager) (new Olympic record)
- 2012 Ezekiel Kemboi
- 2008 Brimin Kipruto
- 2004 Ezekiel Kemboi
- 2000   Reuben Kosgei
- 1996 Joseph Keter
- 1992 Matthew Birir
- 1988 Julius   Kariuki
- 1984 Julius Korir

As a side note, Kenya didn't appear in the 1980 Moscow Olympics, [due to the US-led boycott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1980_Summer_Olympics_boycott), and also didn't appear in the 1976 Montreal Olympics, due to [African disquiet about the partially ineffective boycott](http://news.bbc.co.uk/onthisday/hi/dates/stories/july/17/newsid_3555000/3555450.stm) of Apartheid-era South Africa. They had previously won the 1968 and 1972 Steeplechase races too. So not since 1964 have a Kenyan team appeared at the Olympics and failed to take home the Gold medal for Steeplechase.

Comment: I mentioned this in my [preview for the steeplechase](https://www.iaaf.org/competitions/olympic-games/the-xxxi-olympic-games-5771/news/preview/men/3000-metres-steeplechase) on the IAAF site. Among the finalists only one - then-defending champion Ezekiel Kemboi, the eventual bronze medalist - has been alive in a world where a Kenyan wasn't the reigning Olympic steeplechase champion. (Kemboi was born in 1982.)