# What is the highest percentage of gold medals by nation for a speciality?

Tags: trivia, history, olympics, records

I think about [men basketball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball_at_the_Summer_Olympics) where in 15/18 editions the gold medal was taken by the USA team.

Is this **83%** (=15/18) the higher percentage of gold medal won by the same country for a single Olympic event?

I would like to consider both summer and winter editions but only specialities that were present in at least 10 editions.

Comment: Archery might be a strong candidate 8 years later.  I have not calculated the ratio yet, though. :-)

Comment: I think some events from [this answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/10749/the-longest-olympic-winning-streak-for-a-nation/10751#10751) might be candidates. You can see women's singles in table tennis and women's archery team competition both at 8/8 (=100%). Both are below 10, which you excluded. There is also 4x100m medley relay with 14/15 (=93.3%).

Comment: It all depends a bit on what you mean by *"speciality"*. My examples from previous comment would drop to lower percentage if considered as table tennis, archery, athletics. (But in your question, you have also provided men's basketball rather than basketball as an example.)

Answer (score 2):

<sub>I know this does not match the condition on *only speciality that were present in leat 10 editions*, but I think 8 editions is relevant enough to be noted. Also, I am answering taking the sport at a whole, since checking 35 sports is easier than checking all its specialities.</sub>

**China in table tennis** seems to be the top one with 87.5% of gold medals over all specialities since its introduction in Seoul 1988!

In [Table tennis at the Summer Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_tennis_at_the_Summer_Olympics) you can see that Chinese players have obtained 28 out of 32 gold medals and 53 out of a total of 100. The other gold medals were for South Korea (3, two of them in Seoul 1988, the other one in Athens 2004) and Sweden (1 in Barcelona 1992).

If you want to see some graphs on something related, you can check [Sport Dominance: The percentage of events each nation has won per sport](http://andybarefoot.com/olympics/dominance.html), in where you see archery (4/4 by South Korea), Table tennis (4/4 by China), Basketball (2/2 by USA) and Synchronized swimming (2/2 by Russia) are the sports in which a specific country has been dominant in Rio 2016.

Comment: I think the OP means *a sport that has featured in the Olympics at least 10 times* by 10 editions

Comment: Uhms, I see. Well, table tennis has been in the Olympics 8 times... this answer may be useful in 8 years :)

Comment: As written by @Rathony I mean a speciality present at at least 10 different editions. I can notice that women single table tennis is played in 8 editions and **all the 8 gold medals were won by a Chinese player**

Comment: @Ale yes, I know. I just checked the ranking on full sports, since checking every speciality needs quite more time.